# If I have multiple components with input fields in vue router, how should I fetch data and store it in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-router, vue-cli

In my vue cli project I have a route *Settings* with 3 child components *SettingsA*, *SettingsB* and *SettingsC*. Each child component has ca. 15 input fields, so it would be too many input fields for one single component.

The goal is to get data from a REST backend with an an axios call when the Route *Settings* is loaded, and populate some of the input fields with the data;
the user can then navigate between the child components and fill/change the input fields, without triggering the axios call which would reload and overwrite the users input field changes.

Since there are 3 child components I use vuex as store. That way the users inputs should not change when he navigates between the child components.

My question is: Where and with what hook should I make the axios call? With beforeMounted on the *Settings* Component?

Maybe there is also a better, already tried design than mine?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)**

You actually not necessarily need vuex. Basic idea is to have parent component `Settings`, which includes `SettingsA`, `SettingsB` and `SettingsC`, which are displayed conditionally using `v-if`. The `Settings` component is holding your state. Changes in the child components form fields trigger events with `this.$emit()`. The parent component listens to the events and updates its state. The state of the form is passed down via `props`.

**Solution using [Vuex actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)**

If you go the `Vuex` route, you will trigger `actions` instead of using `this.$emit()` and update the global store. You should import the actions using `mapActions`. In your components you then have access to the global store using `this.$store`.